# PHP Problem Array to string conversion using FetchAll

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have recently started studying PHP and I'm using Zend Framework v1.12.
I can't print the elements obtained by using *FetchAll()*.

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM team');

$obj = $stmt->fetchAll();


foreach ($obj as $value) {
    
    echo $value;
    
}
```

This is the notice (repeated x7):

> Notice: Array to string conversion

Using *var_dump* I have this:

```
array(7) { 
   [0]=> array(2) {["id_team"]=> string(1) "1" ["nameteam"]=> string(10) "Ac Picchia" } 
   [1]=> array(2) { ["id_team"]=> string(1) "2" ["nameteam"]=> string(4) "test" } 
   [2]=> array(2) { ["id_team"]=> string(1) "3" ["nameteam"]=> string(4) "ciao" } 
   [3]=> array(2) { ["id_team"]=> string(1) "4" ["nameteam"]=> string(2) "oi" } 
   [4]=> array(2) { ["id_team"]=> string(1) "5" ["nameteam"]=> string(3) "xtz" } 
   [5]=> array(2) { ["id_team"]=> string(1) "6" ["nameteam"]=> string(3) "123" } 
   [6]=> array(2) { ["id_team"]=> string(1) "7" ["nameteam"]=> string(1) "x" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Teh object returned by the FetchAll is a Array of Arrays. So when you do the foreach and try to print every object in the array you got that error.
To fix it you should do something like:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM team');

//I renamed this variable to make the code more readable.
$teams = $stmt->fetchAll();


foreach ($teams as $team) {
    
    print_r($team); //This will print the array
    
}
```

Comment: The problem is that print_r is used for debugging purposes only, I want to learn how to print them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, even if it was a trivial problem, I write my solution to the problem maybe it will help someone.

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT *  FROM team');

$obj = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($obj as $value) {
    
    echo $value['id_team'] , $value['nometeam'];
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use loop like this :

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT *  FROM team');

$obj = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    
    echo $value['id_team'].','. $value['nometeam'];
    
}
```